# SSAS 2008/Excel 2007 - Can't see cube

Tags: excel, service, ssas, analysis

I have created a cube in SSAS 2008. In BIDS and SSMS I can see it fine. However, I cannot connect through Excel. I have tried both Excel 2003 and Excel 2007. I must support both and neither work. I can see the database but the cubes do not show up.

I created a dummy cube in the project using the wizard and deployed that to the same database. In Excel 2003, I can see and connect to the dummy cube. Excel 2007 can't even find the server/instance after adding this cube. I have used another computer and received the same results with Excel 2003.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Excel 2010: so far, no solution :(

Comment: My fix was to use IP address rather than servername; no idea why this worked though!

Answer (score 7):

The cube has a property Visible. If it's false, Excel won't list the cube.

To see this property

A) double click on the cube in BI studio's Solution Explorer

B) go to the cube tab

C) right click on either the cube which appears in the Measures pane OR the one in the Dimension pane and choose Properties.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try re-deploying the cube that is giving your problems? Remember you need to also download the OLE DB 9.0 and msxml v6 for Excel 2007. Google search for it and the first result should be the MSDN download page.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem in our organization.  I created a simple Role and added "Everyone" as a member.  I gave the role "Read" access and "None" for Local cube Drill-through access.

After I re-deployed the cube with this role, people were able to connect in excel.